How to draw a zone inside a bezier curve JS
I need to create a zone inside a bezier curve I'm creating. In the case of my project, I'm simulating a traffic lane and I want to have a "capture zone" in it. Can you help me?
I need something like this:

I can make this until now:


var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var cw = ctx.canvas.width
var ch = ctx.canvas.height

function reOffset() {
  var BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  offsetX = BB.left
  offsetY = BB.top
}
var offsetX, offsetY
reOffset()
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  reOffset()
}
window.onresize = function(e) {
  reOffset()
}

var lanes = [
  [{
      x: 100,
      y: 5,
      radius: 5
    },
    {
      move: {
        x: 100,
        y: 5
      },
      line: {
        x: 100,
        y: 125
      }
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 125,
      radius: 5
    },
    {
      move: {
        x: 100,
        y: 125
      },
      line: {
        x: 100,
        y: 250
      }
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 250,
      radius: 5
    },
    {
      move: {
        x: 100,
        y: 250
      },
      line: {
        x: 100,
        y: 375
      }
    },
    {
      x: 100,
      y: 375,
      radius: 5
    }
  ]
];

var isDragging = false
var startX, startY
var selectedShapeIndex

drawAll()

canvas.onmousedown = handleMouseDown
canvas.onmousemove = handleMouseMove
canvas.onmouseout = handleMouseOut
canvas.onmouseup = handleMouseUp

function isMouseInShape(mx, my, shape) {
  var dx = mx - shape.x
  var dy = my - shape.y
  if (dx * dx + dy * dy < shape.radius * shape.radius) {
    return (true)
  }
  return (false)
}

function isMouseInZone(params) {

}

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX)
  startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY)
  for (var i = 0; i < lanes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < lanes[i].length; j++) {
      if (isMouseInShape(startX, startY, lanes[i][j])) {
        selectedShapeIndex = {
          group: i,
          index: j
        }
        isDragging = true
        return
      }
    }
  }
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
  if (!isDragging) {
    return
  }
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  isDragging = false
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
  if (!isDragging) {
    return
  }
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  isDragging = false
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDragging) {
    return
  }
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX)
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY)
  var dx = mouseX - startX
  var dy = mouseY - startY
  var selectedShape = lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index]

  if (selectedShapeIndex.index % 2 === 0) {
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].x += dx;
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].y += dy;
    if (selectedShapeIndex.index > 0) {
      lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index - 1].line.x += dx;
      lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index - 1].line.y += dy;
    }
    if (selectedShapeIndex.index < lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group].length - 1) {
      lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index + 1].move.x += dx;
      lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index + 1].move.y += dy;
    }
  } else {
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].move.x += dx;
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].move.y += dy;
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].line.x += dx;
    lanes[selectedShapeIndex.group][selectedShapeIndex.index].line.y += dy;
  }

  drawAll()
  startX = mouseX
  startY = mouseY
}

function drawBez(start, cp1, cp2, end, color, width) {
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, end.x, end.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function getCubicBezierXYatT(start, cp1, cp2, end, T) {
  var x = CubicN(T, start.x, cp1.x, cp2.x, end.x);
  var y = CubicN(T, start.y, cp1.y, cp2.y, end.y);
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

function CubicN(T, start, cp1, cp2, end) {
  var t2 = T * T;
  var t3 = t2 * T;
  return start + (-start * 3 + T * (3 * start - start * T)) * T + (3 * cp1 + T * (-6 * cp1 + cp1 * 3 * T)) * T + (cp2 * 3 - cp2 * 3 * T) * t2 + end * t3;
}

function findCBezPoints(start, cp1, cp2, end) {
  var pts = [start];
  var lastPt = start;
  var tests = 1000;
  for (var t = 0; t <= tests; t++) {
    var pt = getCubicBezierXYatT(start, cp1, cp2, end, t / tests);
    var dx = pt.x - lastPt.x;
    var dy = pt.y - lastPt.y;
    var d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var dInt = parseInt(d);
    if (dInt > 0 || t == tests) {
      lastPt = pt;
      pts.push(pt);
    }
  }
  pts.push(end);
  return pts;
}


function drawAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  lanes.forEach(function(lane) {
    let start, cp1, cp2, end;

    lane.forEach(function(segment, index) {
      if (index === 0) {
        start = {
          x: segment.x,
          y: segment.y
        };
        startLeft = {
          x: segment.x - 9,
          y: segment.y
        }
        startRight = {
          x: segment.x + 9,
          y: segment.y
        }
      } else if (index === 2) {
        cp1 = {
          x: segment.x,
          y: segment.y
        };
        cp1Left = {
          x: segment.x - 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
        cp1Right = {
          x: segment.x + 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
      } else if (index === 4) {
        cp2 = {
          x: segment.x,
          y: segment.y
        };
        cp2Left = {
          x: segment.x - 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
        cp2Right = {
          x: segment.x + 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
      } else if (index === 6) {
        end = {
          x: segment.x,
          y: segment.y
        };
        endLeft = {
          x: segment.x - 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
        endRight = {
          x: segment.x + 9,
          y: segment.y
        };
        drawBez(start, cp1, cp2, end, "#000", 20)
        drawBez(start, cp1, cp2, end, "#fff", 15)
        ctx.restore();

        drawCaptureZone(start);
      }
    });
  });

  lanes.forEach(function(lane) {
    lane.forEach(function(segment) {
      ctx.save();
      if (segment.radius) {
        drawCircle(segment.x, segment.y, segment.radius, segment.color || 'black');
      } else if (segment.width) {
        drawRectangle(segment.x, segment.y, segment.width, segment.height, segment.color || 'black');
      } else if (segment.move) {
        drawLine(segment.move.x, segment.move.y, segment.line.x, segment.line.y);
      }
      ctx.restore();

    });
  });
}

function drawCaptureZone(segment) {
  var captureZone = {
    x: segment.x,
    y: segment.y,
    width: 40, // Adjust the width of the capture zone as needed
    height: 40 // Adjust the height of the capture zone as needed
  };

  ctx.save();

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)';
  ctx.fillRect(captureZone.x - captureZone.width / 2, captureZone.y - captureZone.height / 2, captureZone.width, captureZone.height);
}

function drawCircle(x, y, radius, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawRectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}
<canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>



Codepen example

From the edit guidelines: "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Please remember to show a proper [mcve] by removing all the code that doesn't show off the problem. None of those window/mouse event handlers should be necessary here.

You have the function you need in the example code you provided getCubicBezierXYatT where the last argument T is the unit distance on the bezier. T = 0 will get the start point. T = 1 is the end. To get point near center T = 0.5  Note that T is not linear along the length
